# what check is to be used to confirm that point pattern is random

Tags: spatstat

I have a very basic question. I am not a student of spatial statistics. But for an application, I feel that point pattern on a network is a good approximation for my case. I like the spatstat approach and to limit myself to this package, I would like to ask:

1. Based on some observations, I have the rate (λ = points per km) of occurrence of a point event on a network. Which check(function/test) in `spatstat` should I perform to verify that my point pattern generated by `rpoislpp` is indeed random in nature.

I would be happy if someone could help me in this or direct me to some relevant literature for a beginner level.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard procedure would be to calculate the (network version of the) K-function of the point pattern dataset, and compare this with the envelopes of K-functions for simulated patterns which are completely random.

If `X` is your point pattern on a linear network (class `lpp`) then

```
plot(envelope(X, nsim=19))
```

will give a simple instance of these envelopes.

For more information see chapter 17 of the book cited.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will try your suggestion and get back with questions if any.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `spatstat` I would once again recommend our book *Spatial Point Patterns: Methodology and Applications with R*. Chapter 17 is about point patterns on a linear network. I can assure you that `rpoislpp` indeed generates points that are random in nature. You can just generate a bunch of samples and look at a plot of the patterns to see that they appear very random.

Comment: I share the book  with a colleague so I do not have continuous access. I will definitely look into it when I get access. Hmm, may be  I slightly change my question. If I have an observed point pattern that I know intuitively to be random in nature, How do I say, **because this is random**, rpoislpp is a good method to simulate this pattern. So how do I prove my observed pattern is random.